# Desconozco lo que pasa en este algoritmo de división entre flotantes

Tags: java

El resultado esperado es 0.5f pero en este algoritmo lo que consigo es 0.0f. ¿Que hago mal?

```
public class AlgoritmoDeSequencia
{
    private int n;
    public AlgoritmoDeSequencia()
    {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void algoritmo()
    {
        n = 2;
        float primario = 1/n;
        System.out.println(primario);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando la respuesta de [santiagames](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/62688/4617), Tu algoritmo debería quedar asi:

```
public class AlgoritmoDeSequencia {
    private int n;

    public AlgoritmoDeSequencia(){
        this.n = 2;
    }

    public void algoritmo(){
        System.out.println(1f/n);
        // otras opciones validas
        System.out.println(1.0/n);
        System.out.println((float)1/n);
        System.out.println(1f * 1/n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás dividiendo dos números enteros y eso elimina por completo la parte fraccionaria, ya que el resultado es un número entero.

En el método `algoritmo()` haz lo siguiente:

```
float primario = 1f / n;
```

Answer (score -1):

Buenas, tu problema es que estás diviendo dos números enteros y, por lo tanto, el resultado de la división es un número entero.

Por ello, necesitarás que al menos uno de los dos (divisor o dividendo) sea double o float.

Prueba lo siguiente

```
float primario = 2f/n;
```

Un ejemplo más claro, sacado de la web http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/mixed.html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos